# how to access the element by the value stored in variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

Basically i have an html collection coming up with:

```
  document.getElementsByName('the name')
```

It consists of a select which has options and i want to get the length of the value which works in internet explorer as well as edge browser so i thought of getting it by:

```
  document.getElementsByName('the name').thename.options.length
```

I am getting the value in the console part of my browser but while writing the code and running it is not able to access the `thename` due to some rules I don't know

so is there any way i can get the access of the `.thename.` inside the `document.getElementsByName('the name').thename.options.length`

I hope I am clear with my question as this is an ongoing project and I can hardly make other changes

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: What is your HTML code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thename` is not a built-in object to the HTML `select` element, so you must look for the correct syntax.

I'm assuming you're looking for something like this:

To find the nth option, you would do: `document.getElementsByName('the name')[n-1]`(as this is zero-indexed).

Then you can proceed with the `.value` and `.length` methods.

`document.getElementsByName('the name')[n-1].value.length`

In addition, since this is a syntax error, you may look to online resources first before consulting StackOverflow, as this is general knowledge. Trying to make up syntax or thinking something may be right is also a no-no. Computers are stubborn, and we must be too with them.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement

Comment: yes this is the solution i was looking for thank you so much for understanding the messed up code and my intentions.